# How to convert the CSS to use it in the input type?

Tags: html, css

I need some help with my code. I am using the html code to allow me to post the information when I click on the submit button.

I want to convert the CSS code in the input type of submit, because I am using the two different input type of 'name' and 'email' textbox so I want to get them to work together when I post the information as when I click on the submit button.

Here is the code for the two input types that I currently use:

```
 <input placeholder="Enter Your Full Name" name="name" id="name" class="elInput elInput100 elAlign_left elInputBR5 elInputIRight required0 elInputIName elInputIColor elInputStyle2 elInputBG2 elInputMid garlic-auto-save" data-type="extra" type="text"></div>

<input placeholder="Enter Your Email Address" name="email" id="email" class="elInput elInput100 elAlign_left elInputBR5 elInputIRight required0 elInputIColor elInputIEmail elInputBG2 elInputStyle2 elInputMid garlic-auto-save" data-type="extra" type="text"></div>
```

Here is the code for the input type of submit:

```
<input type="submit" value="SHOW ME THE VIDEO" maxwidth="470"/>
```

Here is the css:

```
input[type=submit] {
    width:89%;
    max-width:470px;
    display:block;
    margin:.05em auto;
    background: #ffef7d; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffef7d 0%, #ffdd57 79%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffef7d), color-stop(79%,#ffdd57)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffef7d 0%,#ffdd57 79%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ffef7d 0%,#ffdd57 79%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ffef7d 0%,#ffdd57 79%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffef7d 0%,#ffdd57 79%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffef7d', endColorstr='#ffdd57',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
border:0px;
padding:.45em 2%;
    font-size:1.9em;
    text-align:center;
    color:#957a11;
        font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
        cursor:pointer;
        -o-border-radius:6px;
        -moz-border-radius:6px;
        -webkit-border-radius:6px;
        border-radius:6px;
        font-weight:bold;
}
```

I want to use the CSS code in the input type of submit so I can see the button color, size, background...etc.

Can you please show me an example of how I can use the css code to convert it to allow me to use it in the input type of submit?

Comment: Could you explain this more clearly? "Convert" may not be the right word. Are you saying you want to take in property values, through user submitted inputs and apply those values to something with JavaScript? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @sheriffderek I want to add width, max-width, display, margin..etc in the input type of submit instead of using css. How I can do that?

Comment: This is still not helpful. Do you mean, 'inline' in the HTML? CSS is how you add styles - so, whether it's in the html or the .css - or the JavaScript - if you want to style something - you are going to have to use CSS.

Comment: no sorry i mean that i want to use something like this `<input type="submit" value="SHOW ME THE VIDEO" maxwidth="470" background="#ffef7d" border="0" text-align="center" ...etc/>` hope you get this?

Comment: That's in my third HTML option in my answer.  : )  `style='property: value; property: value;'`

Answer (score 0):

### HTML

```
<input type="submit" value='Submit me'>
```

or

```
<input class='my-submit-class' type="submit" value='Submit me'>
```

or - You can put your styles 'inline' - in which case your question should be, *"how to I use CSS styles in my HTML markup?"*

```
<input class='my-submit-class' 
       type="submit" 
       value='Submit me'
       style='color: red; display: inline-block;'>
```

(you'll have to understand display: block; vs. inline to get height and certain things to apply)

### CSS

```
input[type='submit'] {
    color: red
    /*
    property: value;
    */
}
```

or

```
.my-submit-class {
    color: red
    /*
    property: value;
    */
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/fuzdvq3p/)